# Am trying to get a specific playlist id and print only it with the youtube api

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to get exactly the 51st playlist id and print it using channelid. Here is my code

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&order=date&channelId=UCpcsv3Ow-8IhoUGDEfPetsQ&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyAZ_vsuKtEN99OnO43NKSLTb51Ajzhxfck
```

I am able to get the first 50 playlists, suppose if I want to print the 52nd playlist, How can I print it? Right now I am using the code below:

```
 response.items[1]['id']
```

How can I print exactly the 52nd playlist by this?

Comment: 51st or 52nd? you seem to have a problem deciding

Comment: @JaromandaX 52nd playlist id sorry for the mistake

Comment: you need to use the `nextPageToken` to get the next 50 ... 52 will be `items[1]` as you seem to have guessed - see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list)

Comment: @JaromandaX how can use page token in url atleast to check

Comment: the documentation clearly states ... `pageToken=?????` in the url query string, where ????? would be `nextPageToken` from the first request

Comment: @JaromandaX I have added the pagetoken in url https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&order=date&channelId=UCpcsv3Ow-8IhoUGDEfPetsQ&maxResults=50&nextPageToken=CDIQAA&key=AIzaSyAZ_vsuKtEN99OnO43NKSLTb51Ajzhxfck but it doesnot work

Comment: the url in your last comment has no `pageToken`

Comment: @JaromandaX updated its showing same 50 list

Comment: RTFM - `pageToken` ... not `nextPageToken` ... you READ `nextPageToken` and SET `pageToken`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks its working